# How to calculate mode value in the column, while ignoring the values "-1" in this column?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate median value of `y` (across rolling window of 5), while not considering the values `-1` of `y` (it happens when X is equal to B).

```
X   y
A    1
A    10
A    10
B    -1
A    1
B    -1
B    -1
A    4
B    -1
```

For example, the first rolling window:

```
X    y
A    10
A    10
A    10
B    -1
A    1
```

Mode value of y is 10.

This is how I calculate median values without the above-mentioned restriction:

```
window = 5
y = y.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.median(x)).dropna()
```

How can I add the restriction of not considering `-1` (the same as not considering rows where X is equal to B)?

I tried this:

```
y = y.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.median(x[x>=0])).dropna()
```

But looking at `y.shape`, it seems that `y` contains less entries than when I do `y.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.median(x)).dropna()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just filter out all -1's?

```
window = 5
y = df[df['y'] != -1].rolling(window).apply(np.median).dropna()
```

Or do you want to still count the -1's in the window size? In which case that would be

```
def mode_wo_minus1(x):
    no_minus1 = x[x != -1]
    return np.median(no_minus1)    
window = 5
y = df.rolling(window).apply(mode_wo_minus1).dropna()
```

Comment: Both solutions provide me less entries in `y` if compared to `y.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.median(x)).dropna()`. I would need exactly the same number of entries as `y.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.median(x)).dropna()` returns.

Comment: Very strange... I have the exact same geometry... Maybe edit your question by providing the code to generate your example data. I'm assuming there is a subtle difference between what you have and what I built based on what you wrote...

Comment: It's difficult to provide a sample of original data.. I will accept your answer as it is, because it gave me some useful hints. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, I appreciate it. But that might make this Q/A a little confusing for future readers, as what you claim does not work (for the data you actually use) *does* indeed work for the example that you gave. May I suggest that either 1/ you remove the part of the question where you say that the "filter" does not work, or 2/ you try to build a simple example that has the same problem as your actual data (and then unaccept my answer, because apparently it does not totally solve your problem).

Comment: Note that taking some time to build a more "realistic" example will probably help you understand what makes your real data different from the current example, and possibly find the solution to your problem :)